# Multiple returns of Returning Users on Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics, analytics, google-analytics-api

Is there a way to find out the number or % of returning users (who come to the website every month) via google analytics?

In other words, I am trying to find out the number of users returning every month to the website (at least for 6 months) not just simply returning once or twice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the short answer is yes.  See [this](http://support.google.com/googleanalytics/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=62504) post for more details

Comment: So your answer is to use User Defined Variables or Custom Variables?

Comment: yeah, you're going to have to be a bit creative about it, but it should be easy enough to figure out

Answer (score 0):

The longer answer is to use a custom variable that is scoped at the visitor level

http://code.google.com/apis/analytics/docs/tracking/gaTrackingCustomVariables.html

that would be populated as 'Repeat Visit' depending on the session number data extracted from the utma visitor cookies:

http://blog.vkistudios.com/index.cfm/2010/8/31/GA-Basics-The-Structure-of-Cookie-Values